# Merging 2 datasets by calling on the row numbers (without using merge() or lookup functions)

Tags: r, merge, lookup

Hi This is a problem that I run into often in R programing and am in need of simple solution from this community.  In sort, the problem requires a lookup value to be returned to a dataframe. I would like to call on the rownumber of the lookup table

```
> x1 <- c(2, 3, 1, 5, 4) 
> x2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
> 
> set.seed(5) 
> x3 <- round(runif (10, 1, 5))
> 
> lookup.df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
> Data.df <- data.frame(x3)
> lookup.df
  x1 x2
1  2  a
2  3  b
3  1  c
4  5  d
5  4  e
> Data.df
   x3
1   2
2   4
3   5
4   2
5   1
6   4
7   3
8   4
9   5
10  1

Data.df$x2 <- df1 [ (matching row numbers from Data.df with lookup.df$x1) , 2 ]
```

In theory, the code should be able to generate a list that would look like

```
rows <- c(1, 5, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3)
```

so that the following would result

```
> Data.df$x2 <- df1 [ rows , 2 ]
> Data.df
   x3 x2
1   2  a
2   4  e
3   5  d
4   2  a
5   1  c
6   4  e
7   3  b
8   4  e
9   5  d
10  1  c
```

I appreciate an ideas. Thanks.

Comment: `matching row numbers from Data.df with lookup.df$x1)` that wouldn't work because row numbers are not in order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a named vector to match

```
Data.df$x2 <- setNames(lookup.df$x2, lookup.df$x1)[as.character(Data.df$x3)]
```

-output

```
> Data.df
   x3 x2
1   2  a
2   4  e
3   5  d
4   2  a
5   1  c
6   4  e
7   3  b
8   4  e
9   5  d
10  1  c
```

Comment: This works very well!  Thank you! I have to fiddle with to see how it works... Why do we convert the list to characters?

Comment: @JamesR We are matching with a named vector.  The x3 column is numeric. If we directly use as numeric, then it will be considered as position indexes which will match based on index and that gives incorrect results

Comment: I think your solution works well and have it in my code already.  I am new to posting on this site and am trying to figure out how to accept both answers, but It seem that I can only accept one.

Comment: @JamesR you can only accept one soluiton.  When I posted, I thought it accomplish the task as you accepted.  If you have another question, please do post as a separate one. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use `match` function -

```
Data.df$x2 <- lookup.df$x2[match(Data.df$x3, lookup.df$x1)]

#   x3 x2
#1   2  a
#2   4  e
#3   5  d
#4   2  a
#5   1  c
#6   4  e
#7   3  b
#8   4  e
#9   5  d
#10  1  c
```

From the title of the post I understand that you don't want to use `merge` function but that would be the most straightforward solution.

```
merge(lookup.df, Data.df, by.x = 'x1', by.y = 'x3')
```

Comment: @Rnoak Shah, Yes, thank you!  match() was the function I was originally looking for and setNames() accomplished the same task.  merge() has the unfortunate side effect of reordering columns and rows.  I have been setting ID's and then order() after the merge but it's a bit sloppy when both of these answers can do the same thing in one line without shuffling the data.